# SSL Cert - Tomcat port fails to start

Tags: java, spring, ssl, tomcat

I'm trying to configure a SpringBoot application with SSL/TLS. When I add the below into application.properties,I get "The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured". Port 8443 isn't in use, and when I remove the configuration I can access port 8443, can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong?

```
server.ssl.key-alias=alias
server.ssl.key-password=passwd
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:path/to/hostname.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
security.require-ssl=true
server.port=8443
```

Comment: There should be a full stack trace in the logs. What does it show?

Comment: Changed keystore type to pkcs12, seems to have solved it.